# Force Outlook Filter Refresh

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, office365

In Outlook 365 I use a filter showing unread and flagged items as my primary view rather than my inbox.  This works well except that read items don't disappear from this filter view until I move to another folder and then back.  Is there a way to force the refresh of this filter on demand?  My ideal method would be a button to tell it to refresh.  If I need to do VBA for this, that is acceptable as well, but not preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Autohotkey macro to switch to my inbox and then back to my unread folder when I press F12 from within Outlook.  It's certainly not an ideal solution and may not work depending on the version of Outlook you have, names of folders, and whether the folder view is collapsed or open.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32  ;If Outlook is active.
F12::                                  ;If F12 is pressed.
{
   SetControlDelay -1                  ;Improves reliability.
   ControlClick, x15 y400              ;Switch to the Inbox.
   ControlClick, x20 y238              ;Switch to the Unread folder.
}
```

return